# MAX function not working on HIVE

Tags: hive

My SQL query:

```
select * from cds2 where tw=(select max(tw) from cds2) limit 10;
```

I am new to Hive and I wrote up this Hive query:

```
Select * from cds2 join (select max(tw) twmax from cds2) V on (1 = 1)
group by id,filename,tw;
```

The above query doesn't work.I would appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select max(f1) as maxf1 from t_ext_1_bkdoubledelete) t1  left outer join (select * from t_ext_1_bkdoubledelete) t2 on t1.maxf1=t2.f1;
What you do i

Comment: It gives me a syntax error.It says syntax error near unexpected token 'from'.Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: I got corret answer in my hive.So what version do u use?Can you put the sql you executed and the output, cause I run it very well